# PHP - Sort video lists from Youtube API with usort

Tags: sorting, youtube-api, strcmp, usort

I have this query
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key=my_key&part=snippet,statistics,liveStreamingDetails&id=videocode_a,videocode_b,videocode_c;

$obiekty=json_decode($json);

Because Youtube API doesnt have any sorting functions i try to sort result itself with usort by scheduled start time with one of two functions

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp(substr($a->liveStreamingDetails->scheduledStartTime,11,2),substr($b->liveStreamingDetails->scheduledStartTime,11,2));
//substr strips result to two hour digits

}

function cmpr($a, $b){
    $godza = $a->liveStreamingDetails->scheduledStartTime;
    $vala = $godza[11].$godza[12].$godza[14].$godza[15];// 4 digit time 
    $godzb = $b->liveStreamingDetails->scheduledStartTime;
    $valb= $godzb[11].$godzb[12].$godzb[14].$godzb[15];

    if ($vala==$valb) return 0;
    else {
        if ($vala>$valb) return 1;
        else return -1;
    }

}

usort($obiekty, "cmpr");
```

But none of them works. How to sort those json results?